# Integrating product of multivariate normal and univariate normal to find marginal

Tags: joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

Suppose, $y_i|u_i\sim MN(X_i(t_i), \sigma_e^2I_{m_i})$ and $u_i\sim N(0,1)$. Now how to find the marginal distribution of $f(y_i)=\int f(y_i|u_i)f(u_i)du_i$? Since one is multivariate normal and other is univariate normal, can we actually find the product before the integration? Or it will be a no-closed form expression? Even if it's the case, how do we come up with the no-closed form expression?

Here $X_i(t)=\dfrac{exp[Z_i(t)]}{\int_a^dexp[Z_i(s)]ds}$ and $Z(t)= b(t)^Tc+b(t)^TAU $ So $X_i(t)$ is determined by $u_i$ via $Z_i$

Comment: According to what you have written, the distribution of $y_i$ conditional on $u_i$ doesn't seem to depend depend on $u_i$ so the marginal will be equal to the conditional distribution.

Comment: Jarle Tufto's comment leads me to surmise there is some kind of typographical error in the question.  To avoid premature answers that could turn out to be irrelevant or confusing, I have closed the thread pending edits to clear up its meaning.